# this.setState with fetch result generating "Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended"

Tags: reactjs

I'm calling fetch from componentDidMount and setting state (this.setState) with fetch results. That generates the message below. I don't know how to refactor this.

```
Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.
```

The TL;Dr code is something like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        urls : props.urls,
        tags : [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.state.urls.forEach((rec) => {
      var tags = this.state.tags
      var dict = {}
      fetch(rec.url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => parse(result))
        .then(result => {
          dict[rec.url] = { rec: rec }
          this.extractMetaTags(rec.url, result, dict)
          return dict
        }).then((d)=>{
          this.setState({tags: tags.concat(d)})
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);  
        });
    }
}
```

The rest of the Warning message shows:

```
* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: fb.me/react-derived-state

Please update the following components: j
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the problem was with an imported component (react-image):

```
<Img src={imgsrc} style={{maxWidth: 500}}></Img>
```

I replaced with a standard  tag and that fixed the problem.